# In R, how can I align output of my own function like this?

Tags: r, function, output, alignment, summary

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uem4h.png)

in R, I want to make function that when input is c() of number show mean, var, min ,max of it.
But how can I align the output just like picture WITHOUT using summary()  ?

is there any function which print like that?? EXCEPT summary()

Comment: There are a ton of functions that create similar output. This should work: `doBy::descStat()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we want to get the summary of selected statistics, use `lapply` to loop over the `list` and get those output based on an `if/else` condition

```
lapply(iris, function(x) if(is.numeric(x)) 
   c(mean = mean(x), var = var(x), max = max(x), min = min(x)) else table(x))
```

-output

```
#$Sepal.Length
#     mean       var       max     min      
#5.8433333 0.6856935 7.9000000 4.3000000 

#$Sepal.Width
#     mean       var       max       min    
#3.0573333 0.1899794 4.4000000 2.0000000 

#$Petal.Length
#    mean      var      max     min     
#3.758000 3.116278 6.900000 1.000000 

#$Petal.Width
#     mean       var       max      min     
#1.1993333 0.5810063 2.5000000 0.1000000 

#$Species
#x
#    setosa versicolor  virginica 
#        50         50         50
```

---

It can be wrapped into a function

```
summary_fun <- function(dat) {
 lapply(dat, function(x)
     if(is.numeric(x)) {
   c(mean = mean(x), var = var(x), max = max(x), min = min(x))
   } else if(is.character(x)|is.factor(x)) {
       table(x)
    } else NA
    )
  }
```

and then call

```
summary_fun(iris)
```

Comment: oh, sorry, I want to use built-in function. Does one of apply function work like that?

Comment: @kongkkk it is a built-in function in a package

Comment: Ah I think its not what I want to find. but thank you.

Comment: @kongkkk I think the updated one matches the one you showed in the image

Comment: I have a question. What should I do when I want to handle "else" ? I mean I want to print table when the class is just char and factor,  not every else

Comment: @kongkkk you can specify with `else if(is.character(x)|is.factor(x)) do this else NA`

Comment: okay that is perfect. but when I try to use this code in myownfunc <- {} this form, what I have to return..? , can you update that form too ? sorry for bother you

Comment: @kongkkk i updated by wrapping into a function

Comment: I want to call only summary_fun(iris)  and print just like the picture :(

Comment: @kongkkk i thought you could have made those changes.  Anyway updated it

Comment: I start R yesterday so this is great help to me for learning it. really thanks. Can I mention you when I ask other things? (in R)

Comment: @kongkkk please don't mention me in your posts.  Sometimes, when somebody answer, they don't realize how much the questioner knows.  Apologies on my part